# How to convert TIMETZ to TIMESTAMPTZ in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a column of timestamps with the type TIMETZ. How do I copy it to an empty column with the type TIMESTAMPTZ with today's date?

Comment: Ugh... `TIMETZ` is a really bad data type that is not consistently defined. My [very personal] take is that PostgreSQL should deprecate it for good. In short, a time with "time zone" but without a date doesn't make sense. A time with "time offset" and no date still makes sense, though.

Comment: @TheImpaler, its is part of the SQL standard so I don't see it going away. Also the docs [Datetime](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) provide a heads up: "The type time with time zone is defined by the SQL standard, but the definition exhibits properties which lead to questionable usefulness."

Comment: @AdrianKlaver "...it is part of the SQL standard..." -- Yes, unfortunately it is; but there are a myriad of things of the standard that are not implemented. Don't want to start a religious war, but there's nothing wrong about deprecating a part of the SQL Standard that doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like so:

```
--Given this:
select current_date  + '08:00'::timetz; 
2022-02-11 08:00:00-08

--Do this:
update some_table set timestamp_tz_col = current_date + time_tz_col;
```

Comment: However, in this example `'08:00'` lacks a time zone.

Comment: No it does: `select '08:00'::timetz; 08:00:00-08`

Comment: And if you want to make it explicit `select '08:00 PST'::timetz; 08:00:00-08` . It won't make a difference to the answer as `PST` is my current timezone. Given that Ermek Barmashev is doing the update in a single timezone context it won't make a difference there either.